# TPL Dataflow TransformBlock Execution Sequence Seems Out Of Order / Async

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm following along this **[MSDN Walkthrough - Walkthrough: Creating a Dataflow Pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**. I created a single `TransformBlock` and executed it by doing a `Post` to it.

```
  // Process "The Adventurous Life of a Versatile Artist: Houdini" 
  //         by Harry Houdini.
  downloadString.Post("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/45370/pg45370.txt");
```

Then after that, I call the `Complete` method and have a `Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit:");` line.

Here's the complete code. You can also find it at this stage in [this commit on my github repo](https://github.com/theShiva/TPL-Dataflow/tree/2de92c9afc3884d63efcc95c54ade6dc7429559e).

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace Palindromes.ConsoleApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // 
      // Create members of the Pipeline
      //

      // Download the requested resource as a string

      var downloadString = new TransformBlock<string, string>
        ( url =>
          {
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloading from {url}...");
            string result = null;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
              // Perform a synchronous call by calling .Result
              var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

              if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
              {
                var responseContent = response.Content;

                // read result synchronously by calling .Result 
                result = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                  Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {result.Length} characters...");

              }
            }
            return result;
          }
        );

      // Process "The Adventurous Life of a Versatile Artist: Houdini" 
      //         by Harry Houdini.
      downloadString.Post("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/45370/pg45370.txt");
      downloadString.Complete();

      Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit:");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute this console app, I expect to see the output as follows.

#### Expected Output

```
Downloading from http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/45370/pg45370.txt...
Downloaded 129393 characters...
Press a key to exit:
```

But here's the actual output. (I've run it several times with the same sequence of `Console.WriteLine` output showing up.

#### Actual Output

```
Press a key to exit:
Downloading from http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/45370/pg45370.txt...
Downloaded 129393 characters...
```

Why is the `Press a key to exit` line getting executed before the `TransformBlock`'s `Console.WriteLine`s get called?

Shouldn't the `TransformBlock`'s `Console.WriteLine`s be called first since I am invoking it first, and since this is going to be part of a Pipeline? Also I don't have any `async` code as far as I can tell, and I don't fully know the inner workings of the **TPL Dataflow**, so why does this appear to be executing out of order?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the Press a key to exit line getting executed before the TransformBlock's Console.WriteLines get called?

The call to `Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit:")` happens before the `TransformBlock` has completed the transform function. Each item posted to the `TransfromBlock` will be processed asyncrounously with respect to your primary context.

Going forward if you want to wait for your pipeline to complete you will need to either block on its `Completion Task` or `await` the completion in an `async` method:

```
private static async Task MainAsync() {
    // Process "The Adventurous Life of a Versatile Artist: Houdini" 
    //         by Harry Houdini.
    downloadString.Post("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/45370/pg45370.txt");
    downloadString.Complete();

    await downloadString.Completion;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So when the various blocks are chained together in the pipleline like so => `//Connect the dataflow blocks to form a pipeline.   //
      downloadString.LinkTo(createWordList);
      createWordList.LinkTo(filterWordList);
      filterWordList.LinkTo(findReversedWords);
      findReversedWords.LinkTo(printReversedWords); ` what part of the walkthrough code ensures that the output from the previous block is fed as input to the next block? ex: output from `downloadString` is sent as input to `createWordList` (but only after `downloadString` has completed, right?

Comment: @Shiva _ex: output from downloadString is sent as input to createWordList (but only after downloadString has completed, right?_ Correct, the `LinkTo` will ensure that output from one block is passed to the input of the linked block. Additionally you can add, to the `LinkTo`, `DataflowLinkOptions` such that `PropagateCompletion` is `true`. With that set when you call complete on the first block, completion will propagate through your pipeline and you would `await` completion on the final block in you pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The `Post` method will return after the posted item is stored in the block's input queue, it will not wait for it to be processed.

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194836(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method will return once the target block has decided to accept or decline the item, but unless otherwise dictated by special semantics of the target block, it does not wait for the item to actually be processed. For example, ActionBlock will return from Post as soon as it has stored the posted item into its input queue).

The items from the input queue are then processed asynchronously.